# How to make tablix visible based on parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a Report which has 3 parameter values ABC,BBC,CBC and i have three tablix TAB1,TAB2,TAB3 .

my requirement is to
Display tablix TAB1 when parameter is set to ABC
Display TAB2 when parameter is set to BBC
display Tab3 when patrameter is set to CBC
what is the expression i need to write in visibility property of each tablix.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have one report parameter with 3 values or 3 different report parameters

Answer (score 6):

for TAB1:-

```
=iif(Parameters!parametername.Value="ABC",false,true)
```

for TAB2:-

```
=iif(Parameters!parametername.Value="BBC",false,true)
```

for TAB3:-

```
=iif(Parameters!parametername.Value="CBC",false,true)
```

This is a pretty easy task. [**Here is more about SSRS Parameters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464.aspx)