# First newbie question: SSRS Tablix visibility parameter

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS: I have two tablix.  One dataset.
Tablix 1 = Summary
Tablix 2 = Details
I would like to set a parameter for the user to choose.  I do not have a field in the data to use as a parameter to differentiate.  I have to use the tablix itself.  By name in report code or by visibility in the tablix?

I've tried everything I could find on Stack overflow.  But I have used a method in the past with a code in the report properties.  But I can't find the code.

I would like the user to choose summary or details or both.  Then see the corresponding tablix

Comment: Have you looked at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620662/how-to-make-tablix-visible-based-on-parameters-in-ssrs

Comment: I tried this first.  It was one of the initial posts I found.  I kept getting an error message.  It was something like "hidden expression conversion type object...

Comment: @Chris thanks for being the first to reply to my very first question.

Comment: @Corene It sounds like an issue with your `Hidden` expression. Please edit your question to include the expression you are using to hide the table and the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your scenario on my local report project.
I create a mutlivalue parameter.
[image: Multivalue parameter]

Then I have available values as below

[image]

Then I added below expression on visibilty of Summary Tablix.

```
=IIF(Parameters!ChooseTablix.Count>1,false,
IIF(Parameters!ChooseTablix.Value(0)<>1,true,false))
```

Below expression for Details Tablix

```
 =IIF(Parameters!ChooseTablix.Count>1,false,
    IIF(Parameters!ChooseTablix.Value(0)<>2,true,false))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  This worked.  I had my expression wrong.  I am so very grateful for everyone's input and time!

Comment: Cool would be great if you mark it as solved. Would help others as well.